# Perl: Programatically set POST param using REST::Client module

Tags: perl, http, rest, post

I've built a REST Server and now I want to rapidly test it from a Perl Client, using REST::Client module.

It works fine if I perform GET Request (explicitly setting parameters in the URL) but I can't figure out how to set those params in POST Requests.

This is how my code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use REST::Client;

my $client = REST::Client->new();

my $request_url =  'http://myHost:6633/my_operation';

$client->POST($request_url); 
print $client->responseContent();
```

I've tried with something similar to:

```
$client->addHeader ('my_param' , 'my value');
```

But it's clearly wrong since I don't want to set an HTTP predefined Header but a request parameter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It quite straight forward. However, you need to know what kind of content the server expects. That will typically either be XML or JSON.

F.ex. this works with a server that can understand the JSON in the second parameter, if you tell it what it is in the header in the third parameter.

```
$client->POST('http://localhost:3000/user/0/', '{ "name": "phluks" }', { "Content-type" => 'application/json'});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I just wasted an hour of my life - The REST::Client docs actually say to invoke a POST request using an arrayref for the body & headers, which isn't correct! `POST ( $url, [$body_content, %$headers] )`

Comment: I think they mean [] to be 'optional', which is standard unix manpage-speak.

Answer (score 4):

The REST module accepts a body content parameter, but I found to make it work with a string of parameters, you need to set a proper content type.

So the following code works for me:

```
$params = $client->buildQuery([username => $args{username},
             password => $args{password}]);

$ret = $client->POST('api/rest/0.001/login', substr($params, 1), 
           {'Content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not used the REST module, but looking at the [POST function](http://search.cpan.org/dist/REST-Client/lib/REST/Client.pm#POST_%28_$url,_[$body_content,_%$headers]_%29), it accepts a body content parameter, try creating a string of the parameters and send that within the function

```
$client->POST($request_url, "my_param=my+value"); 
print $client->responseContent();
```